# Angular Like Counter

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I wish to make a counter of like on Angular. If there is more like than disklike the square is green and vice versa (see stackblitz link).

Link:
[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjcm6i)

My code seems fair, I debugg with consol.log and alert but without success.

If you can help me, give me advice and enlighten me it would be a great help.

Thank you in advance,
Valentin

Comment: Please don't bind functions in your template for performance reason, bind variables instead!

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with the code link, please try providing the question code in your question itself.

In your code if you would modify your `result()` method to this, you would get the desired output:

```
result() {
  if (this.nbrLove > this.nbrDontLove) {
    return 'green';
  } else if (this.nbrLove < this.nbrDontLove) {
      return 'red';
  }
}
```

Also, there is no need of returning values from `nbrL()` and `nbrD()` methods.

As methioned out in a comment by @Ploppy if would bind a variable to the tenplate, it will be more effecient.

You can do this by calling `result()` in both `nbrL()` and `nbrD()` and binding the background style with a class variable:

```
export class AppComponent  {
nbrLove = 0;
nbrDontLove = 0;
bckColor = 'white'

nbrL() {
  this.nbrLove = this.nbrLove + 1;
  this.result()
}

nbrD() {
  this.nbrDontLove = this.nbrDontLove + 1;
  this.result();
}

result() {
  if (this.nbrLove > this.nbrDontLove) {
    this.bckColor = 'green';
  } else if (this.nbrLove < this.nbrDontLove) {
      this.bckColor = 'red';
  }
  else {
    this.bckColor = 'white';
  }
}
```

}

```
<div 
      [ngStyle]="{'width': '20px',
        'height': '20px',
        'background-color': bckColor}">
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-catcjl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your answer! it works. I did not pay attention

Comment: Thank you for your edit! I understand a lot better! Great for your help